# Web Page popup to login, then save cookie

Tags: powershell, cookies, hta, windows-scripting

I'm looking to download webpages that require a signin (specifically shopgoodwill.com). They don't use BasicAuth so I have to sign in somehow.

Curl allows you to run it with a cookie file, so I'm looking for a way to display a webpage to the user where they can sign in, then, when they close the window, capture the cookie, and store it to a file.

Is there a built-in way to achieve something like this within batch or powershell? Would this be possible with a simple .HTA file (outdated but so is the site I'm using this with)? If there is a simple way to do this in any language really, as long as I can invoke it from the command prompt once I compiled or saved it, I would be very interested.

I looked at the following questions, but they did not involve a user signing in with a ui webpage:

- [Getting a session cookie using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933002/getting-a-session-cookie-using-powershell)
- https://superuser.com/questions/1275923/using-invoke-webrequest-in-powershell-with-cookies

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400119/how-can-i-make-this-powershell-web-request-save-the-session-properly) seemed promising, but none of the answers were working for me (when using invoke-request to download the page using the same session, it wanted me to login, telling me it had not properly loggged in).